# Django and JavaScript Templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, django-templates

I am developing a site, using django as my web framework. There are some pages with sections that are updated via jQuery and AJAX. When the AJAX calls are made to the server, the response is in JSON form, which I use to form the DOM. The problem with this is that stuff can get messy real quick by doing things like this, especially if the JSON gets larger and more complicated:

```
$('#content').html('<p class="new">Load new content</p>');
```

So, how can I use clientside JS templates e.g. handlebars to ease this creation of DOM without making my code messy?

Comment: There are many options, but one that works well for me is using require.js, the require.js text plugin and underscore.

Comment: Thanks but can you point me to some helpful starter tutorial or something?

Comment: The link that @ashfaq.p provided should get you started. There isn't going to be one definitive answer that will fit every architecture, but that should get you going.